# Multiple answer question for the function $f(x)=e^{2-x}x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Considering that I don't use calculators, graphic programs that draw functions, books, let the function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by law

$$f(x)=e^{2-x}x^2=\frac{e^2x^2}{e^{x}} \tag 1$$
Which of the following assertions is **TRUE**? I have these 5 options:

**A:** $f$ has no relative extremes;

**B:** $f$ restricted to $]-∞, 0[$ is increasing;

**C:** $f$ has two points of inflection;

**D:** $f$ has no asymptotes;

**E:** None of the previous answers is true.

---

This is my fast solution hoping that I not make any mistakes: for my eyes and my mind the **A** is *false*, because $f$ will have relative extremes calculating the $f'(x)$. I think that there is almost a root when $f'(x)=0$. Obviously I haven't done the calculations and put it on stand-by. The **D**, for my humble opinion can be *true*: generally I remember that if is $f$ it the typology (1) may have oblique asymptotes. It has no horizontal or vertical asymptotes. Excluding the answers that include calculations I think that the **B** is true: in fact

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$
and imagining to do the calculations in the mind using the Hopital theorem
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$$

Hence I not consider the **C** and **E**.

Comment: Did you mean that $\mathbf B$ is *false*, since $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}=+\infty$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, true for **B**: I imagine that function increases from $]-\infty,0[$ and decreases from $[0,+\infty[$.

Comment: as $x$ increases from "$-\infty$", $f$ *de*creases from "$+\infty$"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes you have understood well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have that $f(0)=0$ and as you noticed $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, therefore of course also $B$ is false (by MVT).

Indeed since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, exists $-a<0$ such that $f(-a)>0$ then $$\frac{f(0)-f(-a)}{0-(-a)}=f'(\xi)<0$$ for some $\xi \in(-a,0)$.

To analize $A$ and $C$ I think we can't avoid to take the derivatives.

Comment: Always the MVT theorem. If it not goes well into my head I don't know how to apply it. :( However thank you very much. Please, can you expain me better the combination why you have written B false being $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$. And if B is false then....C it is true.

Comment: @Sebastiano Since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ then exists $-a<0$ such that $f(-a)>0$ then $$\frac{f(0)-f(-a)}{0-(-a)}=f'(\xi)<0$$ for some $\xi \in(-a,0)$.

Comment: If $f'(\xi)<0$ then in $(-a,0)$ is decreasing?

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes since the function is differentiable, we can exclude that it is increasing (which requires $f'(x)\ge 0$ with $f'(x)=0$ only for "some" isolated point).

Comment: Then  the true is the **D**. If that's the case, it's because I didn't want to do the calculations. It probably has an oblique asymptote but for my question I have written that it is "true". Now I edit it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$ the x axis in an horizontal asymptote.

Comment: But $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$? :-( sigh sigh.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is an [horizontal asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Horizontal_asymptotes) for $x \to \infty$

Comment: Yes but into previous comment there is $x\to-\infty$ :-( Sebastiano Since $\lim_{x→−∞}f(x)=0$ the $x$ axis in an horizontal asymptote. So which one is the right one?

Comment: @Sebastiano Opsss sorry It is a typo I mean $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ :)